# Detailed test reports in SBT using ScalaTest

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

how to let SBT generate more detailed outputs of tests? Now only thing I get is the name of method and stack trace - I would like to have some more control over it, to get rid of stack trace, and possibly have formatted info e.g. expected, actual...

Thank you for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you should get some output. As an example:

```
class ATest extends FlatSpec with ShouldMatchers {
  "Some Object" should "do something and will fail" in {
    1 should be(2)
  }
}
```

will return:

```
[info] Some Object 
[info] - should do something and will fail *** FAILED *** (QuaternionSpec.scala:17)
[info]   org.scalatest.TestFailedException: 1 was not equal to 2
```

Can you show your test code?

To turn off the stacktrace you can use:

```
trace off
```